# MVC 4 Webgrid - Column Width settings using css style is not working

Tags: webgrid, column-width

I am trying to set width for Webgrid column. But it is not working.
Anyone help me please.

Please find below my code

```
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
columns:grid.Columns(
grid.Column(columnName:"ID", header: "ID",canSort:true, style: "id"),
grid.Column(columnName:"Name", header: "Name",canSort:true,style: "name")
)
```

And my css file

```
.webgrid-table { border: 1px solid #98BF21;   }
.webgrid-header { background-color: #A7C942; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left;}
.webgrid-alternating-row { background-color: #EAF2D3; }
.id { width: 20px; }
.name { width: 40px; }
```

Anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the width of the `WebGrid` itself in order to solve this issue.

Add this

```
.webgrid-table { *width*: *specify the width value here* ;border: 1px solid #98BF21;}
```